# DownloadFileAsync on button click

Tags: c#, webclient

I have a webpage that holds a couple of fields like the one below

```
<input type="text" value="1-1-2020" name="startDate" />
<input type="text" value="1-31-2020" name="endDate" />
<button type="submit" name="sbmtButton"></button>
```

I'm wondering is it possible to navigate to the page this is held on and then trigger the submit button and download the .xls file utilizing `WebClient`.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: With the assumption the HTML you provided is in a <form>.... you should be able to use a WebClient to do a POST to the endpoint configured in the form's action attribute.

Comment: Alright, how would I go about sending the data for the form then?

Comment: Dr. Google is your friend.  'C# WebClient POST Example'.